# LWC code for following, Hardcode data

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html

i wanna display following on UI, can someone please tell me what changes need to be done in code.

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4">
                <div class="slds-box">
                    <lightning-tile>
                            <dl class="slds-dl_horizontal">
                                    <div class="slds-dl_horizontal__pair">
                                      <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">Opportunity Name</dt>
                                      <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">Opportunity Amount</dt>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-dl_horizontal__pair">
                                        <dd>12345</dd>
                                        <dd>paytolimit</dd>
                                    </div>
                                </dl>
                    </lightning-tile>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-4">
                <div class="slds-box">
                    <lightning-tile>
                            <dl class="slds-dl_horizontal">
                                    <div class="slds-dl_horizontal__pair">
                                      <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">Opportunity Name</dt>
                                      <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">Opportunity Amount</dt>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-dl_horizontal__pair">
                                        <dd>12345</dd>
                                        <dd>paytolimit</dd>
                                    </div>
                                </dl>
                    </lightning-tile>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of json objects where each json object denotes a tile.

The array will be defined in the javascript

```js
  get tiles() {
    return [
      { id: 1, name: 'opp 1', amount: 123 },
      { id: 2, name: 'opp 2', amount: 124 },
      { id: 3, name: 'opp 3', amount: 125 },
      { id: 4, name: 'opp 4', amount: 126 },
      { id: 5, name: 'opp 5', amount: 127 }
    ];
  }
```

In the HTML, use `for:each` directive to loop through the array and display the tiles

```html
<template>
  <div class="slds-card slds-var-p-around_small">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters_direct-xx-small">
      <template for:each={tiles} for:item="tile">
        <div
          key={tile.id}
          class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-var-m-vertical_x-small"
        >
          <div class="slds-box">
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                  <div class="">Opportunity Name</div>
                  <div class="slds-truncate"><a>{tile.name}</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                  <div class="">Opportunity Amount</div>
                  <div><b>{tile.amount}</b></div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked